# How can i know if a given SPWeb is a SearchCenter site programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, spweb

I have a SPWeb object and I want to know whether or not this is a SearchCenter site. How can I know it programmatically. Is there some setting to check or a guid to match etc?

Answer (score 1):

A SearchCenter is created from a special site template that you can identify from the [WebTemplate](http://www.codeplex.com/sharepointinstaller/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=34752) property on the SPWeb object. It will carry the value 'SRCHCEN'.

Comment: Thanks. However, property __WebTemplates is blank when i try to check it for a SPWeb that I know is a SearchCenter.

Comment: Ok. This works. SpWeb.WebTemplate is a property on SPWeb directly. 
That shows SRCHCEN for searchcenter with pages and SRCHCENTERLITE for one without pages. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but the Feature ID GUID shown [here](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/08/enumerate-features.html) might be a global one.